# Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException

Tags: spring, hibernate

I'm working on Spring boot project.
Actually, refactoring code.

And getting this mistake as follows:
Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: ru.kataproject.p_sm_airlines_1.entity.Document, at table: passenger, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(document)]

Any ideas?

**Document.java**

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import ru.kataproject.p_sm_airlines_1.util.enums.DocumentType;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name="document")
public class Document {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "document_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "document_gen", sequenceName = "document_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private Long id;

```
@Column(name = "document_type", nullable = false)
private DocumentType documentType;

@Column(name = "document_number")
private String documentNumber;

@Column(name = "registration_address")
private String registrationAddress;

@Column(name = "where_issued")
private String whereIssued;

@Column(name = "department_code")
private String departmentCode;

@Column(name = "date_of_issue")
private LocalDateTime dateOfIssue;

//todo one to one link to person entity
@Column(name = "person")
private String person = "link to person entity";
```

}

**Passenger.java**

```
import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "passenger", schema = "public")
public class Passenger {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    @NonNull
    @Column(name="document")
    private Document document;  // Заглушка , здесь должна быть сущность Document

    @NonNull
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @NonNull
    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String first_name;

    @NonNull
    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String last_name;

    @NonNull
    @Column(name="middle_name")
    private String middle_name;

    @NonNull
    @Column(name="date_of_birth")
    private LocalDate date_of_birth;

}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ru.kataproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>airline_project_1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>airline_project_1</name>
    <description>Реализуем функционал авиакомпании на базе прототипа</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <springdoc.openapi.version>1.4.8</springdoc.openapi.version>
        <apache-httpcomponents-version>4.5.13</apache-httpcomponents-version>


    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <version>2.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <version>2.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springdoc.openapi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-data-rest</artifactId>
            <version>${springdoc.openapi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${apache-httpcomponents-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thingsboard</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: This might not solve your problem, but you are using pretty old boot parent (2.5.5) with much more recent starters. I'd advise you move to a recent boot version (maybe 2.7.5 or even 3.0.0-RC1 as GA version should be available by the time you achieve your refactoring) and let spring-boot manage all spring dependencies versions.

Comment: Also, use your refactoring to remove `keycloak-spring-boot-starter` and `keycloak-adapter-bom` which are [very deprecated](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10187). Refer to [this set of tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) to use `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` instead (directly as done in first tutorial or one of the starters to auto-configure it from properties as done in other tutorials).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should map entities with `@ManyToOne` or `@OneToOne` i.e.

```
@NonNull
@ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="document")
private Document document;
```